# If you create a new theory of a model by augmenting the language with constants, does the new theory contain sentences that says anything "original"?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Suppose $\mathcal{M} \models T$ where $T$ is a set of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences. Now create an augmented language by adding all the constants in $\mathcal{M}$:

$$\mathcal{L}^* = \mathcal{L} \cup \{c : c \in \mathbb{M}\}$$

Then create a new theory $T^*$ using the language $\mathcal{L}^*$. Does $T^*$ contain any proposition that is materially different than $T$? I would think no because $T^*$ simply states the same propositions, but is now giving names to the elements, correct? I would think $\mathcal{M} \models T^*$. But is it possible now to find a different model $\mathcal{N} \models T^*$ but $\mathcal{N} \not\models T$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* your "$T^*$" is intended to be the elementary diagram of $\mathcal{M}$? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_diagram

If this is correct, then "$\mathcal{M}\models T^*$" is *almost* true; the issue is that $\mathcal{M}$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-structure, not an $\mathcal{L}^*$-structure. So really what we want to say is that the obvious expansion $\mathcal{M}^*$ of $\mathcal{M}$ is a model of $T^*$.

On the other hand, and I think this might address your question, it is *not* the case that any $\mathcal{N}\models T$ can be expanded to a model of $T^*$, even if $T$ is complete! For example, let $T$ be the true theory of arithmetic, $\mathcal{M}$ be a nonstandard model of $T$, and $\mathcal{N}$ be the standard model of $T$. Then $\mathcal{L}^*$ contains - among other things - a symbol $c$ which corresponds to a non-standard element of $\mathcal{M}$, so $T^*$ contains the sentences "$c\not=0$," "$c\not=1$," . . . But clearly there is no possible assingment of $c$ to any element of $\mathcal{N}$ that would satisfy all of these statements at once.

(Note that this really shows that we should write "$\mathcal{L}_\mathcal{M}$," 
"$T_\mathcal{M}$," etc. instead of using just $*$, since it's important to indicate what model is being used to construct the expansion.

---

EDIT: I'm assuming your last sentence is a typo: since $T^*\supseteq T$, any model of $T^*$ is (the expansion of) a model of $T$, trivially.

Comment: Note that while not every model of $T$ can be endowed with an $\mathcal L^*$ structure which satisfies $T^*$, it is certainly true that for any $N\models T$ we can find some $N'\succeq N$ which allows such an expansion (this is a simple application of compactness).

Comment: @tomasz If $T$ is complete ! Otherwise this is false.

Comment: @Pece: Yeah, that was what I meant (I had thought the assumption implicit, but you might be correct in that it isn't). Otherwise this is trivially false.